# Plot the ECG labels and the ECG using Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I am trying to plot both the labels and the ECG using `Web Flutter`. ECG plotting is happening properly but not the annotations. Can someone suggest me something for this? It should look something like this. 
[image]

Found a library call syncfusion. It shows how to add multiple annotations. But the annotation that I am using is a list.

Answer (score 0):

We have created a simple sample by using annotations in the chart. We have provided two annotations in the annotation list such as **high** and **low** texts for the high and low values in the chart. The two annotations are provided in the annotation property available in the chart which takes a list of type **CartesianChartAnnotation**.

[image]

The sample for reference can be found below.

[Sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/sample548935995.zip)

And, we have analyzed the mentioned query **ECG plotting is happening properly but not the annotations**, but we are not sure of what exactly you are conveying. So, we request you to provide more detailed information for this query so that it will be helpful in providing the solution sooner.